# I would like to give the crontab command priority over current audio stream Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, 18.04, cron, sox

The mp3 will automatically run at the specified time using crontab.

```
*/10 7-21 * * * play /home/mo/document/1.mp3
*/10 7-21 * * * sleep 20;play /home/mo/document/2.mp3
*/10 7-21 * * * sleep 40;play /home/mo/document/3.mp3
```

'play' installed sox.

The problem is that crontab does not work while you are viewing youtube.
Crontab initiated audio will not play until currently playing audio stream is closed.

I want to make the crontab command work even if you are watching youtube.

Comment: if you add `export DISPLAY=:0 && ` before your cron command, does anything change... see answer here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2228704

Comment: you bet. welcome to askubuntu community! I edited your question to add some more tags and be more concise to help other people running into your same problem. I had a lot of fun finding the answer to this, let us know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Direct output to current running display**

According to this post:

[sox failing to execute as a cron entry while another sound app running](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2228704)

Running sox/play from a cronjob requires one to export the DISPLAY variable as if you were running a GUI application from crontab. Simply add `export DISPLAY=:0 &&` to the beginning of your command like so:

```
*/10 7-21 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/play /home/mo/document/1.mp3
```

Also, please note, that when dealing with cronjobs it is best to use absolute paths (/usr/bin/play) so that cron doesn't get confused.